# Nginx blocking webstes with proxy_pass

Tags: http, nginx, proxy

I have an Nginx script that proxied HTTP request using this:

```
proxy_pass http://$http_host$uri$is_args$args;
```

I have a list of websites and I want to make it just these ones accessbile by the proxy. I tried adding an if condition with the name of the host but it doesn't work:

```
if ($uri = 'somewebsite')
{proxy_pass http://$http_host$uri$is_args$args;}
```

It said invalid condition.